# how to reset the data value in modal in vue after close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I receive this object called `business` in my modal as a prop and if `business.type` is international then I want it to redirect to another website after 10 seconds. If it is national then I want to stay in the website. However, suppose if I open the international modal first and then close the modal then it still redirects me to the another website. I want that only if I wait for the 10 seconds then I get redirected to the other website and if I close the modal then the second is reset and I don't get redirected.

My code looks like this right now:

```
<template>
 <modal :show="show" @close="onClose()">
   <div v-if="business.type==='international'">
    redirecting in {{seconds}}
   </div>
   <div v-if="business.type==='national'">
    Welcome to our page
   </div>
 </modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    business: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
 data() {
    return {
      seconds: 10,
      showingModal: false,
    }
  },
 watch: {
    show(val) {
      this.showingModal = val
      if (this.showingModal) this.countDownTimer()
    },
  },
  computed: {
    newBusiness() {
      return this.business
    },
  },
  methods: {
    countDownTimer() {
      if (this.seconds > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.seconds -= 1
          this.countDownTimer()
        }, 1000)
      }
      if (this.seconds === 0 && this.newBusiness.type === 'international') {
        this.$emit('close')
        window.location.replace(`${this.business.website}`)
      }
    },
    onClose() {
      this.seconds = 10
      this.$emit('close')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your Timeout in a variable to clear it (stop your countDown loop) when you close your modal.
Here an exemple with a variable "timer":

```
<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return {
      seconds: 10,
      showingModal: false,
      timer: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    countDownTimer() {
      if (this.seconds > 0) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.seconds -= 1
          this.countDownTimer()
        }, 1000)
      }
      if (this.seconds === 0 && this.newBusiness.type === 'international') {
        this.$emit('close')
        window.location.replace(`${this.business.website}`)
      }
    },
    onClose() {
      if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer)
      this.seconds = 10
      this.$emit('close')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timer id, which is returned from `setTimeout` function.
and after close the modal, clear time out using `clearTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to close the modal before redirection.

```
<template>
 <modal :show="show" @close="$emit('close')">
   <div v-if="business.type === 'international'">
    redirecting in {{ seconds }}
   </div>
   <div v-if="business.type === 'national'">
    Welcome to our page
   </div>
 </modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    business: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
 data() {
    return {
      seconds: 10,
    }
  },
  
  mounted(){
    if(this.business.type === 'international'){
      setInterval(() => {
        if(this.seconds < 1){
          window.location.replace(`${this.business.website}`)
        }

        --this.seconds;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```